# Diferencia entre 2 columnas DataTables

Tags: laravel, datatables

estoy armando un listado de compras en DataTables, tengo todo funcionando solo me falta colocar una diferencia entre el valor total de la compra y el que se ha pagado.

```
var dt_basic = dt_basic_table.DataTable({
      pageLength: 10,
processing: true,
serverSide: true,
paging: true,
      ajax: {
                  url: '/admin/purchases/purchase-data',
                  data: function (data) {
                      data.params = {
                          sac: "helo"
                      }
                  }
              },
      columns: [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'created_at' }, // used for sorting so will hide this column
        { data: 'reference_no' },
        { data: 'supplier_id' },
        { data: 'status' },
        { data: 'grand_total' },
        { data: 'paid_amount' },
        { data: 'grand_total' - 'paid_amount' },
        { data: 'payment_status' }
      ],
      columnDefs: [
      {
          targets: 0,
          visible: false
        },],
```

en este caso yo quiero hacer esto: { data: 'grand_total' - 'paid_amount' }, y colocar el valor de diferencia.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado lo hice directamente en la query:

$query = DB::table('purchases')
->select('id', 'created_at', 'reference_no', 'supplier_id', 'status','grand_total', 'paid_amount', 'payment_status')->selectraw('grand_total - paid_amount as due')->orderBy('id');

agrege selectraw e hice la resta del valor pagado al monto total, y esto muestra la deuda.